# ¿Cómo puedo hacer una tabla dinamica sacando los datos de SQL Server?

Tags: java, android-studio, sql-server

Lo que quiero hacer es una tabla dinámica con valores que tengo dentro de una base de datos `SQL Server` este es el código lo realizo en android y lo pongo en el `while` para que me los muestre todos estoy usando un `TextView` para hacer eso, el `textView` lo tengo dentro de un `container` que es el `scroll`.

```
public void consultar(){
  try{
    Statement stm = conexion().createStatement();
    ResultSet rs = stm.executeQuery(
                        "execute  tcadbcap.dbo.CAP_AUTORIZAPEDURGENTE '" + 
                        D3.toString().trim() + "','" + "H37" + "'," + "0" );
    while (rs.next()){
        Tipo.setText(rs.getString(1));
        Sucursal.setText(rs.getString(3));
        Cliente.setText(rs.getString(4));
        Monto.setText(rs.getString(6));
```

Comment: Lo primero que debes hacer es parametrizar la consulta para evitar posibilidades de Inyección de SQL.

Comment: y como hago eso de parametrizar ? soy nuevo en android

Comment: Deberías de aprender a hacerlo con cualquier ambiente. Usando Java es con los métodos PrepareStatement y SetString/SetInt. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html

Comment: La página de Bobby Tables tiene ejemplos en muchos lenguajes. https://bobby-tables.com/java

Comment: ok muchas gracias vere si puedo resolverlo pero gracias por el consejo

Comment: Respecto a tu pregunta, creo que debes explicar a que te refieres con tabla dinámica y si deseas hacerla dinámica en Java o en SQL.

Comment: la quiero hacer en java pero el entorno que utilizo es android stuido quiero que los datos que me esta guardando de la consulta que realizo me los muestra en una tabla o que genere los textview por medio del codigo para que me muestre la informacion separada

Comment: creo que lo que estás buscando es [como hacer un listview dinámico](https://androidstudiofaqs.com/tutoriales/adapter-personalizado-en-android)

Comment: eso es lo que quiero pero no me saleee

Comment: con SQL server lo quiero hacer

Comment: alguien que me pueda dar un consejo o me pueda ayudar se lo agradeceria muchismo